# How to get explicit session for input_fn when training a TensorFlow model

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, tensorflow

In my training data I have a Unix timestamp that I want to convert to hourOfDay and weekday. From that I want to predict users activity. I use BigQuery to get the data and some some calculations using numpy array in the input_fn. I think I need the session that the input_fn runs under to convert my Tensors to ndarrays. The predictions works and the model trains ok. Anyhow here is the code and the error message:

```
def main():
export_dir = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, MODEL_NAME)

def input_fn_from_bigquery():
    features_dict = dict(
        detectedActivity=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
        time=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], dtype=tf.int64),
    )
    training_dict = dict(
        hourOfDay=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64,default_value=0),
        weekday=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64, default_value=0),
        time=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], dtype=tf.int64)
    )
    label_dict = dict(
        detectedActivity=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64)
    )
    # Create a Reader.
    reader = bigquery_reader_ops.BigQueryReader(project_id=PROJECT,
                                                dataset_id=DATASET,
                                                table_id=TABLE,
                                                timestamp_millis=TIME,
                                                num_partitions=NUM_PARTITIONS,
                                                features=features_dict)
    queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(reader.partitions())
    row_id, examples_serialized = reader.read_up_to(queue, 50)
    features = tf.parse_example(examples_serialized, features=training_dict)
    labels = tf.parse_example(examples_serialized, features=label_dict)
    #get all times as numpy array and divide to correct timeformat
    timearray = (tf.scalar_mul(0.001, tf.cast(features["time"], tf.float32))).eval()
    hourarray = np.zeros(timearray.shape, dtype=np.int64)
    weekdayarray = np.zeros(timearray.shape, dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(timearray.shape[0]):
          hourarray[i] = datetime.fromtimestamp(timearray[i]).hour  # calculate hours
          weekdayarray[i] = datetime.fromtimestamp(timearray[i]).weekday()  # calculate weekday
    features["hourOfDay"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(hourarray, np.int64)
    features["weekday"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(weekdayarray, np.int64)
    return features, labels["detectedActivity"]

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("weekday", shape=[1]),
                   tf.feature_column.numeric_column("hourOfDay", shape=[1])]

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10,10],
                                            n_classes=5,
                                            model_dir=export_dir)

print("Train")
classifier.fit(input_fn=input_fn_from_bigquery,max_steps=10)

def serving_input_fn():
    feature_spec = {"weekday": tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=[1]),
                    "hourOfDay": tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=[1])}
    return          tf.contrib.learn.InputFnOps(features=feature_spec, labels=None, default_inputs=feature_spec)

print("Save model")
dir = classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base=export_dir, serving_input_fn=serving_input_fn)
print(dir)
```

Error message:

> ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`

How can I get the explicit session to pass as eval(session=?) parameter.
Looking forward to any help on this + if there other ways to get weekday and hour from the timestamp. I find my solution rather crude.